# Detecting a Specific Network Connection in Java

Tags: java, networking, request, ip, detect

Is there a way to detect if a computer is connected to a certain IP address - probably by intercepting all requests that go through the network and check if one was sent to a specific IP?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html Maybe this might help?

Comment: Well although that class is cool, I don't think it has the functionality I need - I need to be able to tell if the computer is sending or receiving requests from a specific server.